# Postman / Newman retry in case of failure

Tags: postman, newman

In Newman I want to test to ensure that the response code is correct, response time is reasonable and response values are correct.

In some cases, due to network hiccups or other system conditions, some requests might end up with timeouts or incorrect values that will resolve if the same request was processed a few seconds later.

in such cases, I would like to retry the exact request x times with a Y timeout between requests.

If an iteration pass after a retry, I would like the Newman exit code to be 0 (successful run).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After few hours I had ended up with a function like this:

```js
    function retryOnFailure(successCode, numberOfRetrys) {
        var key = request.name + '_counter';
        var execCounter = postman.getEnvironmentVariable(key) || 1;

        var sleepDuration = 1000;
        var waitUntilTime = new Date().getTime() + sleepDuration;
        if (responseCode.code !== successCode && execCounter <= numberOfRetrys) {
            while (new Date().getTime() < waitUntilTime) {
                // Do Nothing -> Wait
            }
            console.log('Retrying: ' + request.name + '\nGot: ' + responseCode.code + ' Expected: ' + successCode + '\nWaited: ' + sleepDuration / 1000 + 'sec  \nRetry Number: ' + execCounter + ' of ' + numberOfRetrys);
            execCounter++;
            postman.setEnvironmentVariable(key, execCounter);
            postman.setNextRequest(request.name);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```js
    retryOnFailure(404, 4);
```

Comment: yeah, a reusable function is probably the better solution here. it's tough work to get some elegant retry logic with postman/newman. I hope the implement reusable global scripts soon.

Comment: where will we put this script, it it on `test script` section of our postman collection?

Comment: You can place it inside the postman  environment  variable via pm.globals.set()  and do eval() on it each time you need the function

Comment: I’ve tried setting this in a variable and I still get a TypeError with the response code.

Comment: I solved the issue, which I now see you stated in the comments above the function. You have to pass in the response code as an argument for the function.

Answer (score 7):

You can setup a request workflow like this:

Create a collection with a request, then:

In the pre-request tab you can implement a counter:

```
// Counter for number of requests
var counter = environment.counter ? _.parseInt(environment.counter) + 1 : 1;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("counter", counter);
```

Your tests tab would look like this:

```
const code = (responseCode.code === 200);

if (code === 200 && environment.counter < X) {
    // Stop execution
    tests["Status code is 200"] = code;
    postman.setNextRequest();
}
else {
    // retry the same request
    postman.setNextRequest("Name of this request");
}
```

A timeout for the request itself can be configured with the newman CLI:

```
newman run myCollection.json --timeout-request Y
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reusable function for the same

```js
postmanFunctions.common.retryOnFailure(predicate,retryCount,waitbetweenRetrySec,ReroutetorequestifNeeded ,postmanAssertions);
```

- predicate function decides success or failure
- assertion function has all postman assertion
- if reroute is blank then after retry attempts assertions gets executed.
- Flexible polling with retrycount and waittime(if predicate passed no more
  polling/reflow)
- There is a maxflow counter(env var) which limits the number of flow jumps to
  avoid infinite loop

Store the below function in Globals or env:

```js
    () => {
    var sleep = (sleepDuration) => {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() - startTime < sleepDuration) {}
    }
    var sleepByAsyncDelayTime = () => {
        var sleepDuration = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('asyncDelayTime') || 0;
        sleep(sleepDuration);
    }
    var retryOnFailure = (predicate, numberOfRetrys, sleepDuration, reRouteRequestName, postmanAssertions) => {
        var retryCountPerReq_key = request.name + '_retry_count';
        var retryCountPerReq = pm.environment.get(retryCountPerReq_key) || 0;
        var reflowCountPerReq_key = request.name + '_reflow_count';
        var reflowCountPerReq = pm.environment.get(reflowCountPerReq_key) || 0;
        var totalReflowCount_key = 'totalReflowCount';
        var totalReflowCount = pm.environment.get(totalReflowCount_key) || 0;
        var maxReflowCounter = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('maxReflowCounter') || 0;
        var maxReflowCounterPerReq = postman.getEnvironmentVariable('maxReflowCounterPerReq') || 0;

        function clearAndExit() {
            pm.environment.unset(retryCountPerReq_key);
            pm.environment.unset(reflowCountPerReq_key);
            postmanAssertions();
        }

        function retry() {
            sleep(sleepDuration);
            pm.environment.set(retryCountPerReq_key, ++retryCountPerReq);
            postman.setNextRequest(request.name);
        }

        function reFlow() {
            if (totalReflowCount < maxReflowCounter && reflowCountPerReq < maxReflowCounterPerReq) {
                pm.environment.unset(retryCountPerReq_key);
                pm.environment.set(totalReflowCount_key, ++totalReflowCount);
                pm.environment.set(reflowCountPerReq_key, ++reflowCountPerReq);
                postman.setNextRequest(reRouteRequestName);
            } else clearAndExit();
        }
        if (predicate()) clearAndExit();
        else if (retryCountPerReq < numberOfRetrys) retry();
        else if (reRouteRequestName != '') reFlow();
        else clearAndExit();
    }
    return {
        common: {
            sleepByAsyncDelayTime,
            sleep,
            retryOnFailure
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Siva, @JoSSte, Can you please give an example of how to use this?

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips the answer given here ought to work

Comment: @JoSSte, I'm not good at JavaScript predicates. Can you please share an example of how to create and pass predicate and an assertion like status not 400? I am unable to make this work. That's why.

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips the predicate is function where it returns true or false. if its true we don't go to retry loop. just write a small function where status!=400

Comment: @sivasubramanianB, Can you update your answer with  a real example of how to invoke this like the top rated answer?
That should help a lot of people who want to use this easily like me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my retry function that I define in collection pre-request script. It only works when tests are executed via collection :

```js
    Utils = {
        wait: function (that, sleepDuration){
            that.setTimeout(() => {}, sleepDuration);
        },
        withRetry: function(that, expectedHttpStatus, maxNumberOfTries, sleepBetweenTries, businessRetryConditionCallBack, endRetryCallback){

            if (!that.pm.environment.get("collection_tries")) {
                that.pm.environment.set("collection_tries", 1);
            }

            if (((that.pm.response.code != expectedHttpStatus) || businessRetryConditionCallBack())
                && (that.pm.environment.get("collection_tries") <= maxNumberOfTries)) {
                var tries = parseInt(that.pm.environment.get("collection_tries"), 10);
                that.pm.environment.set("collection_tries", tries + 1);
                Utils.wait(that, sleepBetweenTries, maxNumberOfTries);
                that.postman.setNextRequest(that.request.name);
            } else {
                if(businessRetryConditionCallBack()){
                    // On ne passe pas à la requête suivante
                    that.postman.setNextRequest(null);
                }

                that.pm.environment.unset("collection_tries");

                endRetryCallback();
            } 
        }
    };
```

And here is how to use it in request on pre-request or test scripts :

```js
    var expectedHttpStatus = 200;
    var maxNumberOfTries = 5;
    var sleepBetweenTries = 5000;

    Utils.withRetry(this, expectedHttpStatus, maxNumberOfTries, sleepBetweenTries, function(){
        // Retry business condition callback
        return pm.response.json().length <= 0;
    }, function(){
        // End retry callback
        pm.test("Has one result", function () {
            pm.expect(pm.response.json().length).to.equals(0);
        });
    });
```

This code will retry request as long as (http statut is different from `expectedHttpStatus` or `businessRetryConditionCallBack` is true) AND `maxNumberOfTries` is not reached and .

When http statut condition is true and `maxNumberOfTries` is reached, a check is done to verify `businessRetryConditionCallBack`. If not true, collection execution is stopped.